# Does the CLT hold for the inverse CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Fix $q\in (0,1)$, $k\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$ and let $F_k$ and $\Phi$ denote the cdf's of the $\chi_k^2$ and standard normal distribution, respectively
(and $F_k^{-1}$ the inverse function of $F_k$). I'm trying to show that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{F_k^{-1}(q)-k}{\sqrt{2k}}=\Phi^{-1}(q).$$

---

Since $E(\chi_k^2)=k$ and $Var(\chi_k^2)=2k$ this of course looks like an application of the CLT but as far as I can see we can only apply the CLT to the cdf, not its inverse.

Any hints on how to continue are appreciated.

Comment: Rewording my now-deleted comment: are there any independence assumptions available?

Comment: @Clarinetist No, the $F_1^{-1}(q),\ldots,F_k^{-1}(q)$ are fixed numbers.  Note that $F_k$ is a function (the cdf). I've clarified it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the CLT, $F_k((x-k)/\sqrt{2k})\to\Phi(x)$ as $k\to\infty$. Wouldn't this mean that $k+\sqrt{2k}F_k^{-1}(y)$ is approximately $\Phi^{-1}(y)$ as $k\to\infty$?